# Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 2 results. matlab

Tags: matlab

I am getting an above error when I ran this code as a part of the larger program. Weirdly, when I am in debug mode and I step through my code I do not get the error. Anyone can help me figure this out? What am I missing?

```
 results.curves
 sov_nom: [1000×5 double]
 sov_real: [1000×5 double]

 sov_nom = results.curves.sov_nom
```

Thanks in advance!

~Polina

Comment: Your example works fine for me, in terms of I get no error. You're absolutely sure, that the given error is related to the shown code? I can't see any curly braces or dot indexing!? Could you please provide some more details on the error, and some more context, where the shown code is used?

Comment: error is in this line specifically: fcsn(n,:) = curve_fit(t, curve(n,:));

Comment: OK @HansHirse you helped me see where the error is but still don't see the error itself. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What is `results.curves`? Likely there are two of those, which is why indexing it gives you two results. Please read [mcve].

Comment: @CrisLuengo there is only one results.curves - I edited my question

Comment: @CrisLuengo you helped me a lot! I found the source of my error. Thank you!!!!